# Horizontal ListView.Builder() not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have ListView as below in my flutter application:

```
widgetToReturn = ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, innerIndex) {
          return Text("Test");
          
        },
        itemCount: widget.objEvent!.details![index].items!.length); 
})
```

It works perfectly fine with Vertical scroll direction.
But, When I am trying to make it Horizontal as below:

Using:

```
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
```

As below:

```
widgetToReturn = ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, innerIndex) {
          return Text("Test");
          
        },
        itemCount: widget.objEvent!.details![index].items!.length); 
})
```

Issue with Horizontal direction is that nothing displaying on screen and it gives me below error :

> > The following assertion was thrown during performLayout(): 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line
> > 1874 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.
>
> Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we
> should provide substantially more information in this error message to
> help you determine and fix the underlying cause. In either case,
> please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set height for `listview` if you want it `horizontal`, one thing you can do is wrap it with `SizedBox` and set its `height`:

```
SizedBox(
        height: 20,
        child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, innerIndex) {
              return Text("Test");
            },
            itemCount: widget.objEvent!.details![index].items!.length),
      ),
```

if you don't want to set static height you can use `row` and `SingleChildScrollView`:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: List<Widget>.generate(widget.objEvent!.details![index].items!.length, (index) => Text("Test")),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: worked. my silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your ListView builder with expanded

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).